# React bootstrap Carousel not working properly?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsx

I'm new using react bootstrap, and I'm trying to use a Carousel in a new App, however it's giving me this bug  even I import bootstrap css' !
[image]

Here I'm sliding and that happens, also the slide is delayed, here's my code:

```
    import './App.css';
    import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
    
    
          
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossOrigin="anonymous"></link>
    
    
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol className="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div className="carousel-inner">
        <div className="carousel-item active">
        <img className='img'src={require('./boys.jpg')}  width='250px' height="250px"/>
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-item">
        <img className='img'src={require('./boys.jpg')}  width='250px' height="250px"/>
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-item">
        <img className='img'src={require('./boys.jpg')}  width='250px' height="250px"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a className="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a className="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to use React Bootstrap Carousel, but you're mixing up the usage of regular Bootstrap CSS with React Bootstrap components. Let's correct the implementation:

First, ensure you have React Bootstrap installed in your project. You can install it via npm or yarn:

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

or

```
yarn add react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

Then, you can import the required components from React Bootstrap and use them in your code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css'; // Your custom CSS file

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Carousel>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img className="d-block w-100" src={require('./boys.jpg')} alt="First slide" />
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img className="d-block w-100" src={require('./boys.jpg')} alt="Second slide" />
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img className="d-block w-100" src={require('./boys.jpg')} alt="Third slide" />
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In this code:

- We import `Carousel` component from `react-bootstrap`.
- We import the Bootstrap CSS file to ensure that styles are applied correctly.
- We import your custom CSS file if you have any additional styles.
- We use the `Carousel` component provided by React Bootstrap, and each `Carousel.Item` contains an image.

This should resolve the issues you're facing with the carousel component. Make sure to adjust the image paths and any other styling according to your requirements.